# Use Python to login to secure website with token

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python script to login to my bank account to further scrap the transactions I've made. I read a lot on that and it seems that it is not complicated, however I dont succeed in login. I think the issue is that when I post my form, I miss a token which is generated by ?? and I dont know how to retrieve it.

Here is my sample code :

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({
    'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36",
})

url_identification = 'https://accweb.mouv.desjardins.com/identifiantunique/identification'
url_identification_process = 'https://accweb.mouv.desjardins.com/identifiantunique/identification/identificationProcess'

login_data = {
    'fnMemoriserUtilisateurActive': '0',
    'InfoPosteRaa': {},
    'OtherIdRaa': {},
    'nbrCartesMemorisees':1,
    'codeUtilisateur':xxxxxxxxxx,
    'description':{},
    '_tk':{},
    'infoPosteClient':{}
}    

r = s.get(url_identification)
r = s.post(url_identification_process, data=login_data)
print r.text
```

My post redirects me to the `url_identification` web page as I am not able to have the proper token. Any idea how I could retrieve it ? I don't know how it is generated, and as it is a bank website, I'm afraid it is sadely not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

To answer your very question first:

1. The value of `_tk` can be found in the response of GETting `url_identification`, e.g.

   ```
   <input type="hidden" name="_tk" value="86167503-a1e1-4fdf-a661-47348671df9d" />
   ```
2. The value `infoPosteClient` is calculated by a `JavaScript` function `add_deviceprint`. You may need to try simulating the specific behaviour, or just give it a constant value.
3. Other parameters of the POST request to `url_identification_process` including `InfoPosteRaa`, `OtherIdRaa`, and `description`, can be empty (at least in my test run).

I don't have an account of that bank to test with, thus I'm afraid I will not be able to check for further requests.
A piece of advice: I do think `Python` is capable for performing this task, and in fact I personally do many similar things (simulating XHR or other complex things using `Python`). But I guess using a `JavaScript`-based solution (e.g. `PhantomJS`) may be more suitable to your specific case.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'll try it asap. In fact, I'm using Python for the rapidity of prototyping. I'd like to use a .NET solution for the final project.